# Azure WADLogsTable is getting flooded with information traces

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

Azure WADLogsTable is getting flooded with information traces on ServiceRunTime setting reads. Is it possible to configure the service to skip logging these unnecessary information?

Eg:

Getting "DataConnectionString" from ServiceRuntime: PASS (DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).

-Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yup - that's the verbose information.  Azure logs at 5 different levels, [Verbose (5), Information (4), Warning (3), Error (2) and Critical (1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.diagnostics.loglevel.aspx).  You can filter the logs to skip the verbose or other levels as you see fit - an example being setting the log level to Information should capture all your Trace information and above.

To configure the log level, you set this within the [Azure Cloud Project settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx) where the numeric filter will apply, i.e. by filtering on Information you will collect Information, Warnings, Errors and Criticals - if you filter by Error you will collection Errors and Criticals.

It would appear you're either collecting all everything or have you log level to Verbose / All.

HTH

Comment: I have change the .wadcfg filter to transfer information as below,

<Logs bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Information" />

with this, vm only transfer entries up to level 4, no more Verbose entries.

Thanks for your reply...

Comment: Np - remember to mark this as an answer to help others in the future.